# Rotate only a certain part of a frame

Tags: ffmpeg

I tried to solve this for quite some time now and could not find the solution. I would like to select a certain "subarea" of a video and rotate/flip only that "subarea". Like a combination of these two one liners:

```
ffmpeg -i IN.mov -filter:v "hflip,vflip" -c:a copy out.mov
ffmpeg -i IN.MOV -filter:v "crop=out_w:out_h:x:y" out.mp4
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do you want to discard the rest of the image?

Comment: No, I want to keep it.

Comment: What should appear in the background after the area is rotated?

Comment: Yes, select an area rotate it and paste it back into the same vid rotated. Background stays the same. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
 ffmpeg -i IN.MOV
        -filter_complex "[0]split=2[full][crop];
                         [crop]crop=W:H:X:Y,transpose=cclock[crop];
                         [full][crop]overlay='X+h/2-w/2':'Y+w/2-h/2'"   out.mp4
```

The video is split with one copy getting cropped and rotated. The other full copy remains full-sized. Then the edited portion is overlaid on the full portion.

The variables in capital letters should be replaced with your numerical values.